# How to fix Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting end

Tags: flutter, podfile

I checked several times Stack Overflow and my code, but couldn't understand, where is rge ens of input is missing in my Podfile:

[image]

Code

```
    File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
    end
    raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try 
    deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
    end

    require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 
    'podhelper'), flutter_root)

    flutter_ios_podfile_setup

    target 'Runner' do
    use_frameworks!
    use_modular_headers!

    flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
    target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
      end
    end

    post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
       end
    end
```